# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI - and - No action was found on the controller that matches the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build out a new endpoint in API app that already has a lot of other endpoints working just fine.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I am getting two errors:

> Message: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:62342/api/VoiceMailStatus

and

> MessageDetail: No action was found on the controller 'VoiceMailStatus' that matches the request.

Here's the controller:

```
public class VoiceMailStatusController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/VoiceMailStatus")]
    public string VoiceMailStatus(string var)
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

And here's the route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I'm using PostMan:

[image]

There are a LOT of threads here about both of these error messages.  I've read many of them, but have yet to find a solution.  One of them said to change this:

```
public string VoiceMailStatus(string var)
```

to this:

```
public string VoiceMailStatus(string var = "")
```

And while that did get the error to go away and I was able to get inside of the method while in debug, `var` was always just an empty string.

**EDIT: GOT IT WORKING**

In addition to adding `[FromBody]` as per Andrii Litvinov's answer, I also had to do one more thing.  What had been this:

```
public string VoiceMailStatus(string var)
{
     ...
}
```

Is now this:

```
public string VoiceMailStatus([FromBody] VMStatus request)
{
     ...
}
```

And then VMStatus is just a small little class with a single `string` property:

```
public class VMStatus
{
    public string var { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what's your controller called and are there attributes on it?

Comment: see edit to OP with name of controller

Comment: which version of aspnet core are you using? I just tried this with 1.1 and it worked as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you need to apply `FromBody` attribute to your parameter:

```
public string VoiceMailStatus([FromBody] string var)
```

If that does not help try to rename parameter to something else, e.g.: `var1`, because `var` is reserved work in C# and could cause some binding issues, but I doubt that's the case.

Comment: [FromBody] did it!  Thanks!  (and btw -- the third party that will be consuming this API dictated the use of `var`.  I don't like it either.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add this to your controller since you have api in the route config:

```
[RoutePrefix("API/VoiceMailStatus")]
```

and then add this to your action:

```
[Route("VoiceMailStatus", Name = "VoiceMailStatus")]
```

This should tie the action to the url localhost/api/voicemailstatus/voicemailstatus

Comment: localhost/api/voicemail status doesn't match your route config.  it should be localhost/api/voicemailstatus/voicemailstatus because the action and the controller are the same.  To do that you'll want to update your route attribute to [Route("api/VoiceMailStatus/VoiceMailStatus")] unless you have a route prefix attribute on the controller, I'd need to see that part of the code to know.